# In Scala, how can I do the equivalent of an SQL SUM and GROUP BY?

Tags: scala

For example, suppose I have

```
val list: List[(String, Double)]
```

with values

```
"04-03-1985", 1.5
"05-03-1985", 2.4
"05-03-1985", 1.3
```

How could I produce a new List

```
"04-03-1985", 1.5
"05-03-1985", 3.7
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a one-liner. It's not particularly readable, unless one really internalizes the types of these higher order functions.

```
val s = Seq(("04-03-1985" -> 1.5),
            ("05-03-1985" -> 2.4),
            ("05-03-1985" -> 1.3))

s.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
// returns: Map(04-03-1985 -> 1.5, 05-03-1985 -> 3.7)
```

Another approach is to add the key-value pairs one-by-one using fold,

```
s.foldLeft(Map[String, Double]()) { case (m, (k, v)) =>
  m + (k -> (v + m.getOrElse(k, 0d)))
}
```

The equivalent for comprehension is most accessible, in my opinion,

```
var m = Map[String, Double]()
for ((k, v) <- s) {
  m += k -> (v + m.getOrElse(k, 0d))
}
```

Maybe something nicer can be done with Scalaz's monoid typeclass for Map.

Note that you can convert between `Map[K, V]` and `Seq[(K, V)]` using the `toSeq` and `toMap` methods.

---

*Update*. After pondering it some more, I think the natural abstraction would be a "multimap" conversion, of type,

```
def seqToMultimap[A, B](s: Seq[(A, B)]): Map[A, Seq[B]]
```

With the appropriate implicit extension in one's personal library, one could then write:

```
s.toMultimap.mapValues(_.sum)
```

This is the clearest of all, in my opinion!

Comment: "It's not particularly readable"  I think it's perfectly readable.  Lines like that make me glad I'm learning Scala.

Comment: @Malvolio Yeah, I edited my post to qualify "readability" -- for someone who's deeply familiar with the meaning of `groupBy` and `mapValues`, OK, the concise version is best. But it's hard to *infer* the meaning of those functions from the concise expression, and for rusty Scala programmers (such as myself at times) I think the for comprehension would be the easiest to figure out.

Comment: I read it post-edit.  I'd never heard of either groupBy and mapValues (I'm new to Scala), but they were exactly what I *hoped* Scala would have. *De gustibus non disputandum* as my mom always says, but your first solution has the minimum of cruft and so I find the most accessible.

Comment: @Malvolio I appreciate your point of view. When I encounter programming patterns that push the limits of my working memory, I often find there's a useful abstraction that greatly simplifies things. In this case, I think the right abstraction is `toMultimap`. Another example: the typeclasses in Haskell/Scalaz like Functor, Applicative, Monad..., have a cost to learn, but once understood, their application simplifies subsequent high level patterns.

Comment: The clearest would be something like `s.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.sumBy(_._2))`. Having implicit conversions that do sumBy, avgBy could be pretty cool.

Answer (score 13):

There is another possibility using Scalaz.

The key point is to notice that, if `M` is a `Monoid`, then `Map[T, M]` is also a `Monoid`. This means that if I have 2 maps, `m1` and `m2` I can add them so that, for each similar key, the elements will be added together.

For example, `Map[String, List[String]]` is a Monoid because `List[String]` is a `Monoid`. So given the appropriate `Monoid` instance in scope, I should be able to do:

```
  val m1 = Map("a" -> List(1), "b" -> List(3))
  val m2 = Map("a" -> List(2))

  // |+| "adds" two elements of a Monoid together in Scalaz
  m1 |+| m2 === Map("a" -> List(1, 2), "b" -> List(3))
```

For your question we can see that `Map[String, Int]` is a `Monoid` because there is a `Monoid` instance for the `Int` type. Let's import it:

```
  implicit val mapMonoid = MapMonoid[String, Int]
```

Then, I need a function `reduceMonoid`, which takes anything that's `Traversable` and "adds" its elements with a `Monoid`. I just write the `reduceMonoid` definition here, for the full implementation, please refer to my post on the [Essence of the Iterator Pattern](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html):

```
  // T is a "Traversable"
  def reduce[A, M : Monoid](reducer: A => M): T[A] => M
```

Those 2 definitions do not exist in the current Scalaz library but they are not difficult to add (based on the existing `Monoid` and `Traverse` typeclasses). And once we have them, the solution to your question is very straightforward:

```
  val s = Seq(("04-03-1985" -> 1.5),
              ("05-03-1985" -> 2.4),
              ("05-03-1985" -> 1.3))

   // we just put each pair in its own map and we let the Monoid instance
   // "add" the maps together
   s.reduceMonoid(Map(_)) === Map("04-03-1985" -> 1.5,
                                  "05-03-1985" -> 3.7)
```

If you feel that the code above is a bit obscure (but really concise, right?), I encourage you to check the [github project for the EIP post](https://github.com/etorreborre/iterator-essence) and play with it. [One example](https://github.com/etorreborre/iterator-essence/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/specs2/blog/iteratoressence/MapOfMapsSpec.scala) shows the solution to your question:

```
   "I can build a map String->Int" >> {
     val map1 = List("a" -> 1, "a" -> 2, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 4, "b" -> 5)
     implicit val mapMonoid = MapMonoid[String, Int]

     map1.reduceMonoid(Map(_)) must_== Map("a" -> 3, "b" -> 8, "c" -> 4)
   }
```

Comment: Scalaz is really impressive. Very nice!

Comment: +1. You should probably start blogging about such simple use cases where one can start incorporating Scalaz in their project. :) Will encourage more people to look into Scalaz and algebraic functional programming.

Answer (score 8):

I used that pattern `s.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)` from Kipton's answer all the time. It translates pretty directly my thought process but unfortunately isn't always easy to read. I've found that using case class whenever possible makes things a bit better:

```
case class Data(date: String, amount: Double)
val t = s.map(t => (Data.apply _).tupled(t))
// List(Data(04-03-1985,1.5), Data(05-03-1985,2.4), Data(05-03-1985,1.3))
```

It then becomes:

```
t.groupBy(_.date).mapValues{ group => group.map(_.amount).sum }
// Map(04-03-1985-> 1.5, 05-03-1985 -> 3.7)
```

I think it is then more readable than the *fold* or *for* version.

Answer (score 2):

```
val s = List ( "04-03-1985" -> 1.5, "05-03-1985" -> 2.4, "05-03-1985" -> 1.3)
for { (key, xs) <- s.groupBy(_._1)
       x = xs.map(_._2).sum
    } yield (key, x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you can use the [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a `reduce` step:

```
// val l = List(("04-03-1985", 1.5), ("05-03-1985", 2.4), ("05-03-1985", 1.3))
l.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ + _).toList
// List(("04-03-1985", 1.5), ("05-03-1985", 3.7))
```

This:

- `group`s tuples by their first part (`_._1`) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped tuples to their second part (`_._2`) (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within each group (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
l.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ + _)).toList
```