# Improvements for a Map merge function

Tags: scala

I'm writing a function to merge two Map's together.  This is what I have so far:

```
def merge[K, V1, V2, V3](left: Map[K, V1], right: Map[K, V2])
    (fn: (Option[V1], Option[V2]) => V3): Map[K, V3] = {
  val r = (left.keySet ++ right.keySet) map {
    key =>
      (key -> fn(left.get(key), right.get(key)))
  }
  r.toMap
}
```

The function itself works.  You use the function as so:

```
val m1 = Map(1 -> "one", 3 -> "three", 5 -> "five")
val m2 = Map(1 -> "I", 5 -> "V", 10 -> "X")
merge(m1, m2) { (_, _) } 
// returns: 
// Map(1 -> (Some(one),Some(I)), 
//     3 -> (Some(three),None), 
//     5 -> (Some(five),Some(V)), 
//     10 -> (None,Some(X)))
```

I have two questions:

1. I'm worried about the <strike>performance</strike> computational complexity of the `.get` and `.toMap` calls.  Can anyone improve the implementation?
2. I'd like the default function to make a pair of the values (`{ (_, _) }`).  I can't quite get the syntax to do so properly.

***Edit:***
While I originally said performance, I meant computational complexity.  <strike>My guess is that this function performs in O(n•ln(n)) time.</strike>  Looks like my function performs roughly in O(n).  Can it be done in O(ln(n))?

Comment: In response to question 1: you might have a look at Scalaz's monoid typeclass for maps, as [illustrated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142514/in-scala-how-can-i-do-the-equivalent-of-an-sql-sum-and-group-by/7168846#7168846) by Eric Torreborre. Your problem is a little different, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Please have a look at the above example.

Comment: @Kipton The map monoid is impressive.  I'll have to give that some thought to see if that can apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the default function literal use:

```
(fn: (Option[V1], Option[V2]) => V3 = 
  (x: Option[V1], y: Option[V2]) => Tuple2(x,y))
```

You'll have to use merge like this: `merge(m1,m2)()`

I would say don't be worried about performance until you perform some measurements on actual data.

Edit: about performance, by providing a view instead of constructing a map you can get quick "construction" at the expense of lookup - assuming we are dealing with immutable maps. So depending on actual data and use case, you can get better performance for certain operations, but it has a trade-off.

```
class MergedView[K, V1, V2, V3](
    left: Map[K, V1], right: Map[K, V2]
  )(fn: (Option[V1], Option[V2]) => V3 = (x: Option[V1], y: Option[V2]) => Tuple2(x,y)
  ) extends collection.DefaultMap[K, V3] {
  def get(key: K): Option[V3] = (left.get(key), right.get(key)) match {
    case (None, None) => None
    case t => Some(fn(t._1, t._2))
  }
  lazy val tuples = (left.keys ++ right.keys).map(key => key -> get(key).get)
  def iterator: Iterator[(K, V3)] = tuples.iterator
} 

val r1 = new MergedView(m1, m2)() // use parens here for second param list.
```

Comment: Never thought about creating a view object.  Very interesting!  It won't help my use case, but I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: huynhjl this is awesome.  @dave I'm confused by your reply because isn't this a generic solution.  I can turn the view back into a map with... r1.toMap

Comment: @huynhjl, how do I introduce my own key ordering into this?  Thanks.

Comment: @Core - I've forgotten why it didn't work in my particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't worry about `get` -- yes, it will create a wrapper object, but doing anything else will be awkward enough that you shouldn't try unless a profiler shows that to be a problem.

As for `toMap`, yes, that might well slow you down. You may try using [breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).

Regarding complexity of `get` and `toMap`, lookup and add are effective constant time for immutable `HashMap`, which is the default `Map`. See [Performance Characteristics of Scala Collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html).

Comment: I'm less worried about the performance of creating the wrapper objects (which I'll need anyways) than the performance of calling a O(ln(n)) function n times.

Comment: @dave Looking up (ie, `get`) is effective constant time (subject to quality of hash) for the default map (HashMap). See [performance characteristics](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) of Scala Collections.

Comment: Excellent link!  I had been looking for something like that.