# How can I summary in Scala like group by of SQL

Tags: scala

I want to summary in Scala.

I have a list of case class instance.

```
case class Structure(structureFirst:String,structureSecond:String,structureThird:String,count:Int)

val structures = List(
  Structure("first001","second001","third001",1),

  Structure("first002","second002","third002",2),
  Structure("first002","second002","third002",2),

  Structure("first003","second003","third003",3),
  Structure("first003","second003","third003",3),
  Structure("first003","second003","third003",3),

  Structure("first004","second004","third004",4),
  Structure("first004","second004","third004",4),
  Structure("first004","second004","third004",4),
  Structure("first004","second004","third004",4)
)
```

then I want to summary like this SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(Structure.count) FROM structures GROUP BY Structure.structureFirst,Structure.structureSecond,Structure.structureThird;
```

This is output.

```
val result = List(
  Structure("first001","second001","third001",1),
  Structure("first002","second002","third002",4),
  Structure("first003","second003","third003",9),
  Structure("first004","second004","third004",16)
)
```

How can I summary this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142514/in-scala-how-can-i-do-the-equivalent-of-an-sql-sum-and-group-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupBy`, in this almost-one-liner:

```
structures.groupBy(s => (s.structureFirst, s.structureSecond, s.structureThird)).map {
   case (key, ss) => 
      ss.reduce((a,b) => a.copy(count = a.count + b.count) ) 
}.toList.
sortBy (_.count)
```

Comment: Thank you for your best answer Faiz.I'm resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means the best Scala dev in the world, but my novice attempt **yielded** this

```
val result = for (structs <- structures.groupBy(_.structureFirst).values.toList)
  yield { 
    structs.reduce((item, cur) => item.copy(count=item.count + cur.count))
  }

result: List[Structure] = List(
 Structure(first002,second002,third002,4), 
 Structure(first004,second004,third004,16), 
 Structure(first001,second001,third001,1), 
 Structure(first003,second003,third003,9)
)
```

Comment: thank you sberry. I understood how to write code in functionally.