# Cost of Scala's immutable object creation

Tags: scala, immutability

I see posts like the for-comprehension in [1] and it really makes me wonder what the overall implication of using the immutable Map vs a Mutable one is. It seems like Scala developers are very comfortable with allowing mutations of immutable data structures to incur the cost of a new object- or maybe I'm just missing something. If every mutation operation on an immutable data structure is returning a new instance, though I understand it's good for thread safety, but what if i know how to fine-tune my mutable objects already to make these same guarantees?

[1] [In Scala, how can I do the equivalent of an SQL SUM and GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142514/in-scala-how-can-i-do-the-equivalent-of-an-sql-sum-and-group-by)

Comment: Structural sharing means a completely new copy often isn't necessary.

Comment: " If every mutation operation on an immutable data structure is returning a new instance" it is not duplicating the whole instance, immutable structures allow data sharing.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example where performance of for comprehensions is insufficient?

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @Rudiger, I don't need a concrete example. I'm asking a question to try to demystify my understanding of what Scala is doing behind the scenes. This is the second question you've commented on with the same sentence and it doesn't really seem like you are trying to answer the question.

Comment: "what if i know how to fine-tune my mutable objects already to make these same guarantees": good for you, don't bother with immutability! I myself don't bother with compilers, as I already know how to write machine code directly. I wonder why other people do, since my code is much faster than theirs.

Comment: Ziggy, either that was a really snarky comment- or you just touched on what I'm missing in my understanding. So what is the compiler able to do directly for immutable objects? Does it do something to help with the re-allocations and garbage collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the only way to answer these kind of performance questions is to profile them in your real-world code. Microbenchmarks are often misleading (see e.g. [this benchmarking tale](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/java-scala-divided-we-fail/)) - and particularly if you're talking about concurrency the best strategy can be very different depending on how concurrent your use case is in practice.

In theory, a Sufficiently Smart Compiler™ should be able - perhaps with the help of a linear type system (inferred or otherwise) - to reproduce all the efficiency advantages of a mutable data structure. In fact, since it has more information available about the programmer's intent and is less constrained by incidental details that the programmer had to specify, such a compiler ought to be able to generate higher-performance code - and e.g. GCC rewrites code into immutable form (SSA) for optimization purposes. For an example that hits closer to home, many real-world Java programs have perfectly adequate throughput, but have issues with latency caused by Java's garbage collector stopping the world to compact the heap. A JVM that was aware that certain objects were immutable would be able to move them without stopping the world (you can simply copy the object, update all references to it, and then delete the old copy, since it doesn't matter if some threads see the old version while some of them see the new one).

In practice, it depends, and again the only way is to benchmark your specific case. In my experience, for the level of investment of programmer time that's available for most practical business problems, spending x hours on a (immutable) Scala version tends to yield a more performant program than spending the same time on a mutable Scala or Java version - indeed, in the amount of programmer time it takes to produce an acceptably-performing Scala version it would probably be impossible to complete a Java version at all (particularly if we require the same defect rate). On the other hand, if you have unlimited expert programmer time available and need to get the absolute best performance possible, you would probably want to use a very low-level mutable language (this is why LAPACK is still written in Fortran) - or even implement your algorithm directly on an FPGA as JP Morgan recently did.

But even in this case you probably want to have a prototype in a higher-level language so that you can write tests and compare the two to confirm that the high-performance implementation works correctly. Particularly if we're just talking about mutable vs. immutable in Scala, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Write your program, and then if performance is inadequate, profile it and look at the hotspots. If you really are spending too much time copying an immutable data structure, that's an appropriate time to replace it with a mutable version, and carefully check the thread safety guarantees by hand. If you're writing properly decoupled code then it should be easy to replace the performance-critical pieces as and when you need to, and until then you can reap the development time gains of code that's simpler and easier to reason about (particularly in concurrency cases). In my experience performance problems in well-written code are a lot less likely than people expect; most software performance issues are caused by a poor choice of algorithm or data structure rather than this kind of small overhead.

Comment: lmm, I do thank you for taking the time to break this down. Everyone has been asking for concrete examples and performance benchmarks- neither of those I am working on nor seeking to produce. I'm an interested engineer with many questions about a language of which I'm learning rapidly and do not know as intimately as I've like to. I'm a little more than half way through the Programming in Scala book by Martin Ordersky and I just have a lot of questions not too many outlets for getting them answered. THanks again for taking the time to explain some of these concepts.

Comment: Honestly Stack Overflow may not be the best venue for this kind of general question - it's very oriented towards specific, concrete questions that have a single objective answer. But I don't really want to send you to reddit or IRC :/. Scala attracts a lot of repetitive criticism and some scala folk can get quite defensive when a newcomer says something that seems like an attack on the language; it's unfortunate on all sides.

Comment: I'm beginning to see that my questions may not be good for stack overflow. I've been an IRC guy for a long time. I'm on freenode these days and I wouldn't mind hopping in a Scala chat if people would have the time to answer my "what if" and "how does this work" questions more thoroughly. I'm an open source guy myself and I'm not sure if I understand why any community of developers would get defensive over constructive challenges and criticism- seems like that could be a sign... specifically when I'm just interested in learning.

Comment: Well, `#scala` on Freenode might be a better place for these questions, and I would hope that people will be helpful. Honestly, as a huge fan of the language, the community has some issues, partly a legacy of some personalities who have since left or been banned. Scala seems to have hit a kind of "koolaid point" where it's popular enough to receive a lot of criticism, and its attempts to combine OO with functional can end up coming under fire from both sides. Hopefully this is a phase and the community will improve; I already see some encouraging signs. But yeah, the issue is real.

Comment: Honestly- my questions really aren't criticism at all. I'm a java/c++ developer. I've done Groovy quite extensively in the past. I love How Scala didn't punt on compiler errors like Groovy and the type inference is amazing sometimes. I also love how Scala has pulled some of the best things from many different languages. My questions are more of "What exactly was Martin Odersky thinking" and not so much "Why the hell does Scala force this?"

Answer (score 2):

Your question starts with a wrong assumption, based on a misunderstanding of the cost incurring of using immutable objects.

Working with **guaranteed** immutable objects that are build form immutable objects allows you to use **structural sharing**, so you can create new objects based on the old ones without having to resort to a deep copy of the object and you can ,roughly spoken, reuse parts of the object the new on is based on.
So this mitigates the impact of using immutable objects greatly.

So what is the difference to fine-tuned, hand-crafted mutable objects ?

- immutable objects fit better for the FP paradigma
- compile time optimization and checks
- lowers the chance of runtime exceptions

Answer (score 1):

The question is very generic, so it is hard to give a definite answer. It seems that you are just uncomfortable with the amount of object allocation happening in idiomatic scala code using for comprehensions and the like.

The scala compiler does not do any special magic to fuse operations or to elide object allocations. It is up to the person writing the data structure to make sure that functional data structures reuse the as much as possible from previous versions (structural sharing). Many of the data structures used in scala collections do this reasonably well. See for example this talk about [Functional Data Structures in Scala](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNhBQJN44YQ) to give you a general idea.

If you are interested in the details, ***the*** book to get is [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) by Chris Okasaki. The material in this book applies also to other functional languages like Haskell and OCaml and Clojure.

The JVM is extremely good at allocating and collecting short-lived objects. So many things that seem outrageously inefficient to somebody accustomed to low level programming are actually surprisingly efficient. But there are definitely situations where mutable state has performance or other advantages. That is why scala does not forbid mutable state, but only has a preference towards immutability. If you find that you really need mutable state for performance reasons, it is usually a good idea to [wrap your mutable state in an akka actor](http://akka.io) instead of trying to get low-level thread synchronization right.

Comment: I suppose when I formulate the question in a way as to properly convey the result I'm seeking, I tend to get better answers. Thank you! I'm going to buy this book and give a read for sure after I'm done with the Programming in Scala book.