# Scala groupBy + mapValues + map back to initial format. Is there a better way

Tags: scala

In a project I'm working on, I often find myself doing the following pattern.

Given a case class X(a: A, b: B, c:C, d: Int), and a list of such X's xs: List[X],
I want to do the database equivalent of grouping by a,b,c, while summing by d, and having the return type as List[X].

What I usually end up doing is

```
xs.groupBy{case X(a,b,c,d) => (a,b,c)).mapValues(_.sum).map(((a,b,c),d)) => X(a,b,c,d))
```

My question, is there a better/clearer/more idiomatic way of doing this with either the scala standard library or Scalaz (If d is of an arbitrary type with a Monoid instance perhaps)?

Comment: Could you post example list, and example output? I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: will do a bit later

Comment: You might want to look at this scalaz example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142514/in-scala-how-can-i-do-the-equivalent-of-an-sql-sum-and-group-by#answer-7168846

Comment: As far as i am concerned there is no simple way to perform grouping and mapping in "place"(without intermediate collection needed). There is also lack of "zipWith" function on scala collections. Maybe they will be added in the future (java streams allows for grouping with mapping via collectors but anyone who used them will agree their usage is not intuitive)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are trying to achieve, i've found a shorter way to achieve this, you don't have to use mapValues, and then map, instead you can do everything with one map, like this:

```
case class X(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Int){
  def +(that: X) = X(a,b,c, d+that.d)
}

val list = List(X("1","2","3",4),X("1","2","3",5),X("11","22","33",6),X("11","22","33",9))

list.groupBy{
  case X(a,b,c,d) => (a,b,c)}.map{ case (k,v) => X(k._1, k._2, k._3, v.reduce(_ + _).d)}
```

If you can use sum with your class it will be shorter and more cleaner, but reduce isn't that bad either.